# tomcat, hibernate,mysql connection issue

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I have the following error appearing quite frequently on my application. The tech involved are Sturts,hibernate,mysql, tomcat. The strange part is it usually take a fews days for the application to freeze, that is both tomcat and mysql service remaining functional, but the web pages can not be loaded which doesn't make sense to me.

Can someone please give me some ideas or directions to solve the problem? Thanks.

```
WARN (com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1) [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool] - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1ec2ec0 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:107)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:113)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:728)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1258)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:368)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use root user to connect to database from machine other than db server. I would recommend to create a db user which can connect to database from any machine e.g. 'db1'@'%'  (refer : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: thanks for the reminder, the app+tomcat+db is on vps, with mysql config localhost only. I just double checked the hibernate.cfg.xml, the connection username for the app is not `root`. so why does root shows up the in stack? or did I mis-configure log4j?